# Doctrine makes update for no reason

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

When I execute my code Doctrine changes a value in the database to 0 although I never changed the value. There isn't even a Setter-Method for this field.

The field is part of the ID.

How can it be that Doctrine changes the value?

**Edit**

The field belongs to the entity PageNamespaceTranslation, the field which gets modified by doctrine is `language_id`.

I use XML, not annotations.

```
<entity name="exodus\domain\meta\pages\namespaces\PageNamespaceTranslation" table="page_namespace_translation">
    <id name="translated" association-key="true" />
    <id name="language_id" type="integer" column="lang_id" />

    <many-to-one target-entity="PageNamespace" field="translated" inversed-by="translations">
        <join-column name="namespace_id" referenced-column-name="namespace_id" />
    </many-to-one>
```

**UPDATE**

I think I have localized the problem: I have a entity called `InformationObjectAliasPageTranslation` which also have a field called `language_id`. The column `lang_id` is used twice: For the field `language_id` and as part of the foreign key for PageNamespaceTranslation.

The problem occurs when I make following query:

```
SELECT p FROM exodus\domain\meta\pages\InformationObjectAliasPageTranslation p
JOIN p.namespace ns
JOIN ns.translated nst
WHERE nst.namespaceId = :ns AND p.language_id = :langId AND p.title = :title
```

When I add `ns` and `nst` to the select the problem does not occur.

However, when I change the mapping so the column `lang_id` is only used once, there are also no problems.

The mapping of `InformationObjectAliasPageTranslation` in its orginal form:

```
<entity name="exodus\domain\meta\pages\InformationObjectAliasPageTranslation" table="page_translation">
    <id name="translated" association-key="true" />
    <id name="language_id" type="integer" column="lang_id" />

    <many-to-one target-entity="InformationObjectAliasPage" field="translated" inversed-by="translations">
        <join-column name="page_id" referenced-column-name="page_id" />
    </many-to-one>

    <many-to-one target-entity="exodus\domain\meta\pages\namespaces\PageNamespaceTranslation" field="namespace">
        <join-columns>
            <join-column name="namespace_id" referenced-column-name="namespace_id" />
            <join-column name="lang_id" referenced-column-name="lang_id" />
        </join-columns>
    </many-to-one>
```

Can the double use of the column lang_id cause this effect?

Comment: please show us some code (like your annotations or so)

Comment: Doctrine 2 is kind of sneaky.  It uses reflection to get/set properties directly to/from the database.  Also, D2 never calls the constructor.  Like @Tuxes3 says, show us a bit of code.

Comment: @Tuxes3 How about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Doctrine does not support sharing of columns. It behaves strange in that case and inserts are not possible because columns are repeated.

I now use a solution with redundancy instead of using shared columns and it seems to be a better solution after all because these date is often read and hardly ever changed.